# Visual Studio 2022 Angular Project Not Removed From Test Explorer

Tags: angular, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I added a new Angular project in my .NET Framework solution via Visual Studio.  I run my unit tests separately via Visual Studio Code and the command prompt, and all my unit tests pass.  However, something happened with my solution, and now my Angular project is being included in the Test Explorer of Visual Studio along with the rest of the Web and WebApi projects.  This is something I do NOT want, as these unit tests take a long time, hold up my system, and produce erroneous results.  The only way I know to stop VS from considering that folder is to unload the project from the solution, which I really don't want to do.

Can anybody help me figure out how to keep this Angular project in my VS Solution but prevent that entire folder from being considered in the unit test explorer much less run the unit tests in Visual Studio?